# Vectorized Lookup in Dataframe Using Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a numpy array such as the one below, is it possible to use vectorization to return the associated value in column HHt without using a for loop?

```
ex_arr = [2643, 2644, 2647]

for i in ex_arr:

    h_p = df.at[i, "HHt"]
```

Example df:

|  | HHt |
| --- | --- |
| 2643 | 1 |
| 2644 | 2 |
| 2645 | 3 |
| 2646 | 4 |
| 2647 | 5 |
| 2648 | 6 |
| 2649 | 7 |
| 2650 | 8 |

Expected result:
1
2
5

Comment: simply `df.loc[ex_arr, 'HHt'].to_list()`? can you provide code to reproduce `df` (what is the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), if need list or array add [`Series.to_list`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) or [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
print (df.loc[ex_arr,'HHt'].to_list())
[1, 2, 5]

print (df.loc[ex_arr,'HHt'].to_numpy())
[1 2 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just slice with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and convert to list with [`to_list`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html):

```
out = df.loc[ex_arr, 'HHt'].to_list()
```

Output: `[1, 2, 5]`